# SQL Command to Insert Inf, NAN and -Inf into sqlite3 database

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

What is the sql command to insert infinity, negative infinity, and not a number into a real type column in sqlite3 database tables?

i.e what would be in place of value1, value2?

```
INSERT INTO table (column1,column2 ,..)
VALUES( value1, value2 ,...);
```

I have tried finding resources for this on the sqlite3 [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/floatingpoint.html) but was unable to find anything.

Inserting "Inf" and "-Inf" as a string and reading it in via C++ gives me a small -0.00... value

Comment: If you want to store `'Inf'` and `'-Inf'` in a column you should define it as `TEXT`.

Comment: No, they clearly stated they want to store ±infinity. It made sense to try to use sqlite's text representations of ±infinity in the hope that sqlite would be able to convert those to the actual numbers when inserted into a `REAL` column, but annoyingly that only works for finite numbers (e.g. `'123'` will get converted to `123.0`) and not for ±infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Any number that's outside the range of double-precision floats is automatically converted to ±infinity, so e.g. `1e999` will work as literal value for infinity:

```sql
sqlite> create table foo(x real);
sqlite> insert into foo values (-1e999),(-1e308),(0),(1e308),(1e999);
sqlite> .mode quote
sqlite> select * from foo order by x;
-Inf
-9.9999999999999996322e+307
0.0
9.9999999999999996322e+307
Inf
```

Note that these are actual numeric ±infinity values. Text strings would be sorted after numbers, and they would be quoted in output mode `quote`:

```sql
sqlite> insert into foo values ('Inf'),('-Inf');
sqlite> select * from foo order by x;
-Inf
-9.9999999999999996322e+307
0.0
9.9999999999999996322e+307
Inf
'-Inf'
'Inf'
```

<del>I'm not sure however whether you can actually store a NaN.</del> At the very least it appears that any numeric expression that would evaluate to NaN gets implicitly converted to NULL:

```
sqlite> select (0*1e999);
NULL
sqlite> select (1e999-1e999);
NULL
```

<del>though I'm not sure whether that also happens if you directly provide a NaN via the C API.</del>

**UPDATE:** I've checked the source code. SQLite always converts NaN values to NULL, specifically:

- when the result of floating-point arithmetic is NaN
- when NaN is bound to a parameter using `sqlite3_bind_double()`
- when a custom SQL function returns NaN using `sqlite3_result_double()`
- when deserializing a double from the database
- when a NaN literal is encountered while parsing JSON5

Answer (score -2):

you can insert `-Infinity` or `+Infinity` into `real` datatype  as well as `NaN` , etc as it has been mentioned in the documenation:

```
create table input (numbers real);
insert into input values ('-Infinity');
insert into input values ('+Infinity');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=cc1efca81b8685dc358ad4f8cb814b9a)*

but in your c , I think you have to handle it yourself , like when you see '+inf' or '+infinity'

Comment: In your link in dbfiddle numbers were ordered in,
`
0
2
5
+Infinity
-Infinity
NaN.`

If this is correct, should -Infinity not be ordered before 0?

Comment: SQLite uses binary64 to save real datatype , so I'm not sure how it sorts the data , but don't forget infinity and nan are not real numbers, It's just a string value.

Comment: You're storing strings, not ±infinity. SQLite is perfectly capable of storing the actual numeric ±infinity values, it just doesn't have any _nice_ way to enter these values in sql. The easiest way is by just writing a number that's way too large for a float64 and gets rounded to infinity (e.g. `1e999`).